# Electron V5.0.11 not support webgl when running on Apple Silicon

Tags: electron, webgl, apple-silicon

**env:**

*electron: 5.0.11
macos:12.22.1 (apple m1 pro)*

I just run the app like [eletron-quick-start](https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start) by "npm run start".

on the renderer process console, I type code like the below.

```
let can = document.createElement('canvas')
can.getContext('webgl')
// null
```

The weird thing is the first run is ok. "can.getContext('webgl')" return something.

when getContext returns null, I noticed the extra output of console like the below:

```
electron-helper: fallback to sw vertex processing because buildpipelinestate failed
electron-helper:failed assertion clearfunction getclearshaderfragmentfunction
```

I tested the ElectronV11(process.arch:x64) and ElectronV19(process.arch:arm64), Webgl is working fine.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should rather be an issue on github than a question here on stackoverflow.

Comment: The official would say: upgrade your Electron version.  but my Electron app was developed with many Node-addon built by NAN. Upgrading is hard.

Comment: You have two options: find the closest version that still works and review the commits (or do a git bisect) to find out what changed and see if you can affect it (which is quite unlikely) or port your code to a newer supported version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up offering Mac Apple silicon people the app which is built based on Electron above version 16